# Why 'Expect' is waiting even after the arrival of expected pattern in output?

Tags: remote-access, expect

I want to update all my PCs using automated command remotely. This is my code using 'expect' script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set pa "paswoord"
set n1 "user1"
set n2 "user2"

set timeout 2400
spawn ssh $n1@node1
expect "password:"
send -- "$pa\r"
expect "$"
send -- "echo $pa | sudo -S apt-get dist-upgrade -y\r"
expect "$"
send -- "sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y\r"
expect "$"
send -- "sudo apt-get autoremove -y\r"
expect "$"
send -- "exit\r"
expect eof
###END OF node1###

set timeout 2400
spawn ssh $n2@node2
expect "password:"
send -- "$pa\r"
expect "$"
send -- "echo $pa | sudo -S apt-get dist-upgrade -y\r"
expect "$"
send -- "sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y\r"
expect "$"
send -- "sudo apt-get autoremove -y\r"
expect "$"
send -- "exit\r"
expect eof
###END OF node2###
```

and so on...

The problem is if I use timeout = 2400, I will have to wait for a very long time to complete. If I use shorter timeout, then 'expect' does not wait the command to complete.

I want to make 'expect' to run next command right after previous command completed, like bash script. It is possible?

Comment: Even if you give 2400 as timeout, if the command completes before that time, then `expect` will proceed as such. It won't deliberately wait until that time.

Comment: After I run `expect` script, it display `spawn user1@node1` command and `user1@node1's password` but after that it just stay at `user1@node1:~$` for a very long time. It is suppose to be that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because of `expect "$"` which is wrong. If you want to match the literal dollar sign, you have to use

```
expect "\\\$"
```

which will match literal dollar sign.

By the way, you could have created a procedure as

```
proc startUpgrade {user host} {
    spawn ssh $user@$host
    expect "password:"
    send -- "$pa\r"
    expect "\\\$"
    send -- "echo $pa | sudo -S apt-get dist-upgrade -y\r"
    expect "\\\$"
    send -- "sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y\r"
    expect "\\\$"
    send -- "sudo apt-get autoremove -y\r"
    expect "\\\$"
    send -- "exit\r"
    expect eof
}

startUpgrade "dinesh" "xxx.xx.xx.xxx"
```

Alternatively, to match some common known prompt, you can define a variable like

```
set prompt "#|>|:|\\\$"; # We escaped the `$` symbol with backslash to match literal '$'
```

While the `expect` is used, we have to accompany with `-re` flag to specify that as a regular expression.

```
expect -re $prompt
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's been a week I tried to debug this script. I really thought `expect` unable to run such command. It turns out it's just a silly mistake in my script.